# Increments in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I'm trying to give array some values.

So far I have the following code.

```
double[] weeks = new double[10];

for(int i = 0; i < weeks.length; i++) {               
    weeks[0]= 2;
    weeks[9]= 26;
}
```

Week 1 (or `week[0]`) needs to be 2 and week 10 (or `week[9]`) needs to be 26.

I'm trying to identify an algorithm which can be used to equally increment the values of the array between 2 and 26 automatically. Since `26 - 2 = 24` and there are 9 values to be filled after `week[0]`, I have worked out that the increment should be `8/3` or `2.6 recurring`. For example the values should be the following.

```
2
4.6666666666
7.3333333333
...
23.333333333
26
```

Comment: It is rather unclear what you try to achieve and how that relates to the code you have included.

Comment: in my array im trying to increase by increments. I want to basically figure out how to add 2.6 to the sum of the previous index

Comment: `for(double d = 2, d < 26; d += 2.6)`?

Comment: can you elaborate a little more on that? the d represents what ?

Comment: It's a variable. The `i` represents what in `for(int i = 0; i < weeks.length; i++)`?

Comment: Hello. Would you be able to accept an answer which you feel sufficient answers your question, please? As this lets the author of the answer know that they solved your problem and it also lets others know that the problem has been solved. You can do this using the tick next to one of the answers. Also if you feel none of these answers answer your question properly please let us know

Comment: for (int i=1;i<=8;i++) weeks[i]=2.0+i*(26.0-2.0)/9.0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*week 1 (or index 0) needs to be 2 and week 10 (or index 9) needs to be 26*

If I understand you, you want to populate the array `week` with values from `2` to `26` in approximately equal intervals. You could use something like,

```
int min = 2;
int max = 26;
int count = 10;
double inc = (max - min) / (double) (count - 1);
int[] weeks = new int[count];
double init = min;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    weeks[i] = (int) Math.round(init);
    init += inc;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(weeks));
```

which outputs (as requested) from 2 to 26

```
[2, 5, 7, 10, 13, 15, 18, 21, 23, 26]
```

Comment: Why did you change `weeks` to an `int[]`?

Comment: this is essentially what I am trying to accomplish. do I have to use the min and max? I'm trying to do this with as little code as possible.

Comment: @MrMatt the above is calculating everything, you can certainly do it however you please (including using the magic values instead of `min` and `max`).

Answer (score 0):

Here's where math comes in useful:

```
weeks[0]= 2;
weeks[9]= 26;
```

can be seen as

```
f(0)=2
f(9)=26
```

Now, if you want a linear relationship, then `f(x)` is of the form `f(x)=a*x+b`. You already have the two data points above, you just need to solve for `a` and `b`. Hint: you can trivially deduce that `b` should be 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double[] weeks = new double[10];   
        int [] intList = new int[10];
        double increment = 2.666666666666666;
        int sum=0;
        double average=0;
        weeks[0]= 2;
        for(int i = 1; i < weeks.length; i++) {
            weeks[i]= weeks[i-1]+increment;
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(weeks));
    }
}
```

This code outputs

`[2.0, 4.666666666666666, 7.333333333333332, 9.999999999999998, 12.666666666666664, 15.33333333333333, 17.999999999999996, 20.666666666666664, 23.333333333333332, 26.0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SolutionClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] weeks = new double[10];   
        int [] intList = new int[10];
        int sum = 0;
        weeks[0] = 2;
        weeks[9] = 26;
        double average = (weeks[weeks.length - 1]-weeks[0]) / (weeks.length - 1);

        for (int i = 1; i < weeks.length - 1; i++) {               
            weeks[i] = weeks[0] + i * average;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < weeks.length; i++) {               
            System.out.println(i + "; " + weeks[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> 0; 2.0
>   1; 4.666666666666666
>   2; 7.333333333333333
>   3; 10.0
>   4; 12.666666666666666
>   5; 15.333333333333332
>   6; 18.0
>   7; 20.666666666666664
>   8; 23.333333333333332
>   9; 26.0

Answer (score -1):

I am also not quite sure about what you want to achieve, but I might have what your problem might be. If you just want to increase the variable `i` in your for-loop, just write:

```
for(float i=0;i < weeks.length;i+=2.6) {
    //Do your Code here
}
```

But i don't think this is your problem, so please be precise and give an example and write in comments what you expect the code to do.